# Disable date-time range in React-Datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, datetimepicker, datetimerangefield

I have an array of events in which we have objects containing the start and end date of the event.

```
[
  {
    "start": "2020-10-07T15:30:00+05:00",
    "end": "2020-10-07T16:30:00+05:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-10-11T16:00:00+05:00",
    "end": "2020-10-11T20:00:00+05:00"
  }
]
```

I want to disable the range in which an event is occurring in the react-datepicker. So that user cannot select the date or time on which an event is already booked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable only date range then you can use `excludeDateIntervals` props.

But if you want to **disable time also** then check this.

Firstly, make an array of the slots which you want to be disabled like this.

```
let slots = [
{ start: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 13), end: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 14) },
{ start: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 15), end: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 17) },
{ start: new Date(2022, 7, 18, 12), end: new Date(2022, 7, 18, 18) },
{ start: new Date(2022, 8, 1, 9), end: new Date(2022, 8, 2, 13) },
]
```

You can define a object in any proper format or using Date function like this

```
// { start: "08/09/2022 13:00", end: "08/09/2022 14:00" }
// OR
// { start: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 3), end: new Date(2022, 8, 8, 5) }
```

Now use `filterTime` prop of react-datepicker

```
filterTime={(time) => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
                    const e = slots[i];

                    var x = moment(time),
                      beforeTime = moment(e.start),
                      afterTime = moment(e.end);

                    if (
                      x.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime) ||
                      x.isSame(moment(beforeTime)) ||
                      x.isSame(moment(afterTime))
                    ) {
                      return false;
                    }
                    if (i + 1 == slots.length) {
                      return true;
                    }
                  }
                }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude dates and/or times using these two props: `excludeDates` and `excludeTimes`.

Documentation here presents how to do it under "Exclude dates" and "Exclude times" sections. https://reactdatepicker.com/

Comment: Here we can exclude only a single date or array of dates. I think the question says to exclude a range of dates. That's is what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from "moment"
import {extendMoment} from "moment-range"
```

Let's name the data of dates range as `bookings`

```
let bookedDates = [];
bookings.forEach((booking) => {
  const range = moment.range(moment(booking.start), moment(booking.end));
  //The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.
  const dates = Array.from(range.by("day"));
  // The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.
  bookedDates.concat(dates);
});
```

this code must be returned from server to client. In the client, you get the `bookedDates` array. On client side you should convert each date to Date object for React date picker

```
const excludedDates = [];
  dates.forEach((date) => {
    excludedDates.push(new Date(date));
  });
```

Now add this to Datepicker:

```
    <DatePicker
            ....

            // if you want to both checkIn and checkOut date
            selectsRange
            excludeDates={excludedDates}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Muhiq said, the `excludeDateIntervals` attribute can be used for this. It accepts an array of objects, each containing a `start` and `end` values which should be a regular JavaScript `Date`. Using the data from your example:

```
const events = [
    {
        "start": "2020-10-07T15:30:00+05:00",
        "end": "2020-10-07T16:30:00+05:00"
    },
    {
        "start": "2020-10-11T16:00:00+05:00",
        "end": "2020-10-11T20:00:00+05:00"
    }
];

const disabledDateRanges = events.map(range => ({
    start: new Date(range.start),
    end: new Date(range.end)
}));

<DatePicker excludeDateIntervals={disabledDateRanges} />
```

No need to import libraries/manually generate date ranges.